# Responsive design tips for nokia lumia

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, nokia, responsive-design

I'm coding responsive layouts for some big website, I want to test it on most popular mobile devices, as for iphone,ipad there is plenty of information and I can test it on e.g. ios simulator then about nokia lumia there is no any useful information, I don't even know what is web browser there, is there any place where I can find any information about it? Do you have any experience regarding developing www for nokia lumia?

Thank you for any help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the information related to Lumia devices on the [specification pages](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/?filter1=windowsphone). There is also a nice [collection](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Design_and_UX/#!designing-for-nokia-platforms/designing-for-windows-phone-7.html) of guidelines, tutorials that Nokia maintains but they are not specific to web development.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

is most crucial in developing responsive designs for any mobile devices, like a magic wand it solved most of my problems. Hope it helps for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

This media query work well in any Nokia Lumia Mobile.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

// your code goes here

}
```

and add css for table element in windows mobile

```
table-layout: fixed
```